# Who is Chaturpadh Devi?

Tags: devi, goddess, durga

Which god/goddess or energy is known as chaturpad devi? Is there any description available or what is her form and qualities? It would be great if anybody could answer it!

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it ChatuRpad? Or ChatuSpad?